# KnockOut Unable to parse bindings

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, knockout.js

I was reading other answers but I can't find the solution, the error says:
Error: Unable to parse bindings. Message: ReferenceError: AdvertisementLegs is not defined; Bindings value: foreach: AdvertisementLegs, and I cant find why,  becouse its defined in the model:

Here is the models

**Main Model.js**

```
self.selectedAd = ko.observable();

    self.selectAd = function (item, data) {
        self.selectedAd = ko.observable(new AdvertisementMgr());

        self.advertisementManager().getAdvertisementById(item);
        $('#windowEditAd').jqxWindow('open');
    };
```

**Advertisement Model.js**

```
var self = this;

//URLS

self.CompanyName = ko.observable("");
//Lists
self.AdvertisementLegs = ko.observableArray();

    self.getAdvertisementById = function (dataItem) {
    $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        url: mViewModel.apiUrl + 'Advertisement',
        type: "GET",
        contentType: "json",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
            adId : dataItem.AdvertisementId()
        },
        success: function (data) {

            mViewModel.selectedAd(data);
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            alert(error.message);
        }
    });
};
```

the json response is:

```
CompanyName
    "Flotsum Strategies, Inc"


AdvertisementLegs
    [Object { AdvertisementLegId=6, Action="BUYER", Volume=1, más...}]

0
    Object { AdvertisementLegId=6, Action="BUYER", Volume=1, más...}

AdvertisementLegId
    6

Action
    "BUYER"

Price
    0

AdvertisementId
    4

AdvertisementLegType
    "TL"
```

The view is:

```
    <div data-bind="with: $root.selectedAd">

    <span data-bind="text: CompanyName"></span>     
    <input data-bind="value: CompanyName" type="text" class="txt4 leg_data_vol1" style="width: 50px; text-align: center;" id="leg_data_vol1" />




    <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="volaxe-table">
        <tbody data-bind="foreach: AdvertisementLegs ">
            <tr >
                <td>

                    lalla

                    <input data-bind="value: Volume" type="text" class="txt4 leg_data_vol1" style="width: 50px; text-align: center;" id="leg_data_vol1" />
                </td>
            </tr>

        </tbody>
    </table>
 </div>
```

CompanyName has no problem the issue is with the array it says
Message: ReferenceError: AdvertisementLegs is not defined.
Why it says that it cant bind it if its in the model and it has results?

Comment: AdvertisementLeg is an object in json maybe its that but I don't know how to inicialize it.

Comment: Where is your view model?  Is anything else binding properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
self.selectedAd = ko.observable(new AdvertisementMgr());
```

This is no good because after you applyBindings and then call `selectAd`, you overwrite your observable reference with a new observable.  You want:

```
self.selectedAd(new AdvertisementMgr());// Or do you?
```

Sure this isn't supposed to be:

```
self.selectedAd(new Advertisement()); // ?
```

---

I also noticed in your getAdvertisementById method, you do this:

```
mViewModel.selectedAd(data); // No bueno
```

self.selectAd function fires off and sets the selectedAd to a new AdvertisementMgr.  Then you getAdvertisementById.  You make your ajax call and on success, you set the selectedAd again, but you're doing it with the raw data object that comes back.

```
function Advertisement(data) { ... }
```

Then

```
myViewModel.selectedAd(new Advertisement(data));
```

In your Advertisement model, ensure all properties are being set to default values and also ensure properties that need to be observables are being set as observables.

Answer (score 1):

This is because when the initial bindings are applied, `selectedAd` defined as null when created as `ko.observable()`, and doesn't have any property `AdvertisementLegs` until it is set to `new AdvertisementMgr()` in `selectAd`.

You should check that `selectedAd` is not null before attempting to bind to it's properties. You could wrap your entire `<div data-bind="with: $root.selectedAd"></div>` container with a knockout `if` to ensure that it's non null before being rendered/bound.

So just wrap your whole markup with `<!-- ko if: $root.selectedAd() --><!-- /ko -->` which unwraps `selectedAd`, makes sure it's not null, and doesn't attempt to render until that element is non null.

```
<!-- ko if: $root.selectedAd() -->
<div data-bind="with: $root.selectedAd">

  <span data-bind="text: CompanyName"></span>     
  <input data-bind="value: CompanyName" type="text" class="txt4 leg_data_vol1" style="width: 50px; text-align: center;" id="leg_data_vol1" />
  <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="volaxe-table">
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: AdvertisementLegs ">
        <tr >
            <td>
                lalla
                <input data-bind="value: Volume" type="text" class="txt4 leg_data_vol1" style="width: 50px; text-align: center;" id="leg_data_vol1" />
            </td>
        </tr>

    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<!-- /ko -->
```